# How can I change the default focus on 'JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog' pop-up from 'Ok' button to the 'textfield'?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

How can I change the default focus on `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` pop-up from `Ok` button to the `textfield`?

My code:

```
public String userPassword() {

    Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();

    JLabel j1 = new JLabel("Password: ");
    box.add(j1);

    JPasswordField jpf = new JPasswordField(24);
    box.add(jpf);

    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, box, "Enter your password", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    char[] input = jpf.getPassword();

    String password = String.valueOf(input);
    return password;

}
```

Comment: Closed as a duplicate. Note that some of the answers in the linked question are a bit questionable, but **this** one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21426340/3182664 should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` you can use a `JOptionPane` to create the desired dialog as follows:

```
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(box, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION)
{
    @Override
    public void selectInitialValue()
    {
        jpf.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
};

optionPane.createDialog(null, "Title").setVisible(true); // pass your parent if possible and and define your title
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have used your code and it perfectly serves my purpose. Thank you so much for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

*JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...)* itself **calls** *JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(...)*
then you can simply use *JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(...)* like below

```
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                box,
                "My Message Dialog",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
                null, new Object[]{"Ok", "Cancel"}, box);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I used your code and the focus issue was resolved. I tested the application and found that the 'enter' key wasn't working to act on behalf of 'Ok' button click. So I am using the code of kAliert. Thanks!